# Why does an object still exist after std::move function?

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue

I have a question regarding std::move function. Please refer to the code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

class CPointer {
public:
    CPointer(double a, double b)
    {
        m_dX = a;
        m_dY = b;
    }

    ~CPointer()
    {
        m_dX = m_dY = 0;
    }


    double getX() const
    {return m_dX;}

    double getY() const
    {return m_dY;}

private:
    double m_dX;
    double m_dY;
};

class CContainer 
{
public:
    CContainer(CPointer* p)
    {
        m_p = p;
    }

    ~CContainer()
    {
        m_p = nullptr;
    }

    CPointer* getP() const
    {return m_p;}

private:
    CPointer* m_p;

};


class CBigContainer
{
public:
    CBigContainer(CContainer* p)
    {
        m_p = p;
    }
    ~CBigContainer()
    {
        m_p = nullptr;
    }
    CContainer* getP() const
    {return m_p;}

private:
    CContainer* m_p;
};

int main()
{
    CPointer* pPointer = new CPointer(150,360);

    cout << "1.) " << pPointer->getX() << " , " << pPointer->getY() << "\n";

    std::shared_ptr<CContainer> spContainer = std::make_shared<CContainer>(pPointer);

    cout << "2.) " << pPointer->getX() << " , " << pPointer->getY() << "\n";

    std::shared_ptr<CBigContainer> spBigContainer = std::make_shared<CBigContainer>(std::move(spContainer.get())); //<--- std::move here

    cout << "3.) " << spBigContainer->getP()->getP()->getX() << " , " << spBigContainer->getP()->getP()->getY() << "\n";
    cout << "4.) " << spContainer->getP()->getX() << " , " << spContainer->getP()->getY() << "\n";
    cout << "5.) " << pPointer->getX() << " , " << pPointer->getY() << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

And this is the result :

[image]

My question is , I am using a std::move

```
std::shared_ptr<CBigContainer> spBigContainer = std::make_shared<CBigContainer>(std::move(spContainer.get()));
```

So I am expecting the **spContainer** cannot be used after the line of code, because the object inside smart pointer is removed.
But it still work fine. It seems like has no different with not using std::move in this case.

Can you explain to me in details ?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So I am expecting the spContainer cannot be used after the line of code, because the object inside smart pointer is removed.

Your code never actually requests any move operations. The smart pointers are a red herring, you could see the same behaviour in this case:

CContainer a(pPointer);

CBigContainer b( std::move(&a) );

The last line is the same as `CBigContainer b( &a );` because the constructor of `CBigContainer` accepts a pointer, and the behaviour of move operations for primitive types (which includes pointers) is to leave the source unchanged.

Your code makes the `CBigContainer` object point to the `CContainer` object (the latter still being managed by a smart pointer).  Which is a bad idea because if you then release the `CContainer` smart pointer, then the `CBigContainer`'s pointer to it will dangle.

Your `CContainer` and `CBigContainer` objects hold raw pointers to other objects. Putting those objects in smart pointers doesn't change that.

---

In case you are unclear, these are two different things:

- Move out of a smart pointer.
- Move out of the object managed by a smart pointer.

The first one will leave the smart pointer empty. The second one leaves the smart pointer active and managing an object which is in a post-move state .

Here's an example of code that will move out of the spContainer:

```
std::shared_ptr<CContainer> other = std::move(spContainer);
```

This invokes a move operation because the `shared_ptr` on the left has a move-constructor 
 which accepts another `shared_ptr` of the same type as argument.